# Problem reading certificate & key in Nodejs Express for HTTPS

Tags: node.js, https, certificate

I am trying to add a certificate to my Nodejs Express Service to get HTTPS working. I followed this answer to start with: [Enabling HTTPS on express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js)

Although I only have `.cer` and `.txt` (my key) files, so I just manually renamed the `.txt` to `.key`. I then changed the lines in the above answer to this:

```
-- HIS ANSWER:
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

-- MY CHANGE:
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server.cer', 'utf8');
```

My `.cer` looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
JHfw2AWawdDH...
...hd8h28HDFWA
-----END PKCS7-----
```

My `.key` looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
HDW28HD82HD2...
...82FHJD12
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

But when I start my service, the line `var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);` throws this error:

```
      c.context.setCert(cert);
                ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

I have tried many other answers to this questions but I am still not getting it to work. I have little knowledge about certificates and HTTPS so any explanations will help a lot :)

Comment: How did you generate these certificates. Seems like certificates are invalid

Comment: We got them from the company where we bought them, or something like that, should I request new ones or a resend or something? Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: I can't grantee that but that may help

Comment: I will give that a shot thank you