# How to run angular universal HTTPS

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal

I'm follow angular universal in homepage: https://angular.io/guide/universal 

Without universal, I run my angular project with command

> ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key --ssl-cert /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt --host 0.0.0.0

Now, I add universal to my project, but don't know how to setting it run with "https".
 Help me, please.

Here my server.ts

> import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
>   import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
>   // Express Engine
>   import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
>   // Import module map for lazy loading
>   import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
>   
>   import * as express from 'express';
>   import {join} from 'path';
>   
>   // Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
>   enableProdMode();
>   
>   // Express server
>   const app = express();
>   
>   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
>   const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
>   
>   // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically  from webpack
>   const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');
>   
>   // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
>   app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
>    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
>    providers: [
>      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
>    ]
>   }));
>   
>   app.set('view engine', 'html');
>   app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);
>   
>   // Example Express Rest API endpoints
>   // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
>   // Serve static files from /browser
>   app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
>    maxAge: '1y'
>   }));
>   
>   // All regular routes use the Universal engine
>   app.get('*', (req, res) => {
>     res.render('index', { req });
>   });
>   
>   // Start up the Node server
>   app.listen(PORT, () => {
>     console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
>   });

Comment: You could enable https for express (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js), but if you are using a reverse proxy (Apache, nginx), then you could just configure the proxy to use https instead

Answer (score 2):

So this Question has been open for too long:

I myself tried to solve this problem. My first approach was changing the server.ts express server so it would create an HTTPS instance instead of an HTTP one. This failed as it tried to start the file in a docker container.

So back to the beginning I started the node server with HTTP and used an Nginx server as a proxy to connect to the node server. This also has the benefit that your web application is capable of connecting with more clients.

In your Nginx config file there should be something like this:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  SERVER.com;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/live/SERVER.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/SERVER.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass DESTINATION:PORT;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps ;)