# fs.readFileSync Cannot read file passing path variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

I am trying to read xml file using fs.I am not able to read file using fs.readFileSync after passing path variable as first paramter to this function.
Note:this is in windows machine

```
xmlFile="C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\.proxySettings.xml";
function myFunc(xmlFile) {
 let xmlData = fs.readFile(xmlFile);
 alert(xmlData);//doesn't print anything

 parser = new DOMParser();
 xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData,"text/xml");
....
....
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <proxy_port>2582</proxy_port>
```

update in the file

```
 try{
    ffile="jdkdkj";
  fs.readFileSync(ffile); 
}catch(err){
  app.console.log(err);
}

Error { errno: -4058, syscall: 'open', code: 'ENOENT', path: 'jdkdkj' }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code so we can help you

Comment: Hi Mark, I have edited the question

Comment: Your code shows `let xmlData = fs.readFile(xmlFile);` which will never work as `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous and requires a callback as the second argument to communicate back the result.  Also, your backslashes in the path have to be double escaped.

Comment: I tried with readFileSync

Comment: let io="C:\\cygwin64\\xyz\\tmp.txt";
var data=fs.readFileSync(io);
alert(data); //doesn't show anything

Comment: but same works if  var data=fs.readFileSync("../../../tmp.txt); alert(data);

Comment: It takes path that is relative and it creates problem when that is absolute !!!

Comment: This is related, and I haven't found the answer yet: https://github.com/browserify/brfs/issues/36

Comment: try building path with `path.join()`. Also,it's best to have that file on an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the backslash character is used to signal that the character immediately following it should be treated specially. In order to create a literal backslash inside a JavaScript string you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

```
var a = "\abc";
console.log(a); // abc
var b = "\\abc";
console.log(b); // \abc
var c = "\"abc\"";
console.log(c); // "abc"

xmlFile="C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\.proxySettings.xml";
console.log(xmlFile); // C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\.proxySettings.xml
```

So, windows pathnames always need double backslashes in JavaScript

Comment: I tried this  xmlFile = xmlFile.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\'); but still it doesn't print file contents

Comment: You should be able to do xmlFile="C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\.proxySettings.xml";  let xmlData = fs.readFile(xmlFile);

Is xmlFile assigned a pathname in your code as a string literal? Or is it read from a database?

Comment: Then you don't need the replace(), using double backslashes should work. Let us know how it goes

Comment: It didn't read the file when I passed a path varaiable as first parmater to readFile or readFileSync

Comment: When I do fs.readFileSync("file-that-doesnt-exist") I get an exception that looks like this: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'foo'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35) errno: -2, syscall: 'open', code: 'ENOENT', path: 'foo' }  

Are you seeing something like that?

Comment: Please update your question with the error message and the current version of lines of code that read the file. Also provide the output of the windows command prompt running a dir xmlfilename