# Unable to call http api from https server in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have a angular application which is deployed in the secures server. Now it's working in the https.

Same way i have nodejs application which is running in the amazon ec2 linux server using pm2. which is running in http

I tried to use that http api in https web app I'm getting error i.e
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://ec2-13-***********.amazonaws.com:3000

Can any one help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default the nodejs runs in http. Enabling https will resolve the mixed content issue.

[This answer might be helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975)