# how I can redirect from http to https express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, http, https

I am serving React build directly. So please consider it for your answer.

```
import express from "express";

let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

...
// // All start from index.html
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is online: " + port);
});
```

Comment: I need to fix my website: http://goodutube.com

Comment: You can chk - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114/639406 may be its helpful