# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, angular9

I have a project on NodeJs(backend) and Angular9(frontend). I was doing a SignUp.
I have this api from the backend(NodeJs) side

```
             http://localhost:3001/account/login
```

and upon implementation the project was running and it moved me from the SignUp page to other pages within the application and it was moving me from the login page to another page inside the application,
But I changed the api, instead of http, I put https

```
         https: // localhost: 3001 / account / login
```

But the application no longer works. It just displays the SignUp page, and when I enter the data it does not transfer me to other pages.
And I have this error that appeared when I Click "Inspect" in Chrome:

```
        POST https://localhost:3001/account/login 
        net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

How Can I Solve This Problem?

Comment: Can you include some code, so we can get a clear picture of your problem?

Comment: You need to trust the self-signed certificate you use. Either add it into the certificate store or visit `https://localhost:3001` in the browser and manually accept the security exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and I've found a solution here

If you have using the express framework for your rest API, then the following solution work for you
First, you need to create a "cert and key" file using the following command

`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt`

After that please put the below code into your express.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/selfsigned.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/selfsigned.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// your express configuration here

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

I've taken a reference from the [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114)