# How do I set up SSL with Namecheap, Heroku, Express & React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl, heroku

I've successfully purchased SSL from Namecheap and set up SSL manually for Heroku, but navigating to the HTTPS url instead of HTTP doesn't work. I'm not sure what the next steps are. Does this need to be handled in both React and Express?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", does it redirect to HTTP, or time out connecting, or is there an SSL error? React would never be the piece terminating SSL, since that's just frontend code. You could terminate in Express, but shouldn't have to assuming it's set up properly on the Heroku side.

Comment: SSL setups are handled on the sever so React shouldn't be part of this conversation. Based on your post, I am assuming you're running express. Here is how to set up SSL on express: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114/1927991