# I want to render a node.js page with headers served by http2

Tags: node.js, ssl, rendering, http2, partials

I couldn't find the answer.

How would I serve **EJS headers**, which normally are in the "**views/partials**" directory in the application root, while I'm using **HTTP2 module** server instance.

Here is my code:

```
const http2 = require("http2")
const fs = require("fs")

const server = http2.createSecureServer({
        "key": fs.readFileSync("./ssl/private.pem"),
        "cert": fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem")
})

server.on("stream", (stream, headers) => {

        stream.respond({
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "status": 200
        })

        stream.end(JSON.stringify({
                "user": "Moi",
                "id": "823"
        }))
})

server.listen(443);
console.log("listening on port 443");
```

I want to **achieve the same** thing **as in the code following this block of text**, but then doing that in the code above this block of text.
Where in the original code it is rendered using `<%- include('partials/header'); %>` which happens in the "*reviews.ejs*" file. (Which is the file which is **rendered** from the views directory which also holds the **partials** directory, which holds the **header.ejs** file and the **footer.ejs**).

So, I need to replicate the following code:

```
app.get("/reviews", function(req, res) {
  res.render("reviews"); // I need to replicate this line with HTTP2!
});
```

And I need to replicate this:

```
app.post("/updated", function(req, res) {
  username = req.body.username;
  email = req.body.email;

  console.log(username, email);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

So, my final question is, how do I replicate those last two snippets of code, in the code of the 1st snippet? **cough** **cough** My eyes are square **cough**

(Or any better way to **employ SSL**, and render my new site like the old one which used **EJS** / **view engine** w/ the **partial headers**)?

---

|_|> (me):

Thanks (and you're probably a nerd, no offense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount the express application to the HTTP server you are using the following way.

```
const server = http2.createSecureServer({
    "key": fs.readFileSync("./ssl/private.pem"),
    "cert": fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem")
}, app); // app is Express application that is a function that can handle HTTP requests.
server.listen(...);
```

Update: I am not sure that Express supports `http2` but I am sure that the same code will work for `https` module if the thing you need is `SSL`.

Comment: Thank you.
Yeah, I'm really trying to get SSL working on my website.
It is really hard to find a decent explanation for this.

In particular, now I'm looking for a method to render the page along with the headers, while having SSL functioning.

Comment: Sorry am new, can't upvote yet. How do I mark it correct?

Comment: When you hover over my answer, near the upvote and downvote, right below there should be a check icon.

Comment: Roger. Checked it. So, can you show me how I am supposed to create https routes? Or, do I just use the App method for that? I have not found the time to try out your solution yet. Just point me at the documentation, please. I need a way to serve the certificate, and a way to render the same headers as with EJS View Engine I was using. I want SSL and use the same (specific) header and footer files with several pages. Does the HTTPS lib cover it? Primarily I just want the best way to host a CA certificate, which certificate I already have. Everything over https and use header/footer like w/ EJS.

Comment: You just need to use the app, and that is it. Create a typical HTTPS server and mount express application to  it. Then you can write your express app in the same way as always. Here is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USrMdBF0zcg][1]

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hello from SSL server')
})

// app.listen(3000, () => {})

const sslServer = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem'))
}, app)

sslServer.listen(3443, () => console.log('Secure Server on port 3443'))


// SELF-SIGNED CERTIFICATE
// openssl genrsa -out key.pem
// openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
// openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Still need to check if my Post routes work...

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I have now is:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

const audience_id = process.env.AUDIENCE_ID;
const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;
const api_string = "thisIsNotMyRealAPIKeyPhrase:" + api_key;

const url = "https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + audience_id;

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem'))
}, app)

app.use(favicon(__dirname + "/public/images/favicon.ico"));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home");
})

// etc ...
```

And at the end of the file:

```
server.listen(3443, () => console.log('Secure Server on port 3443'))
```