# How to use a url that starts with https as a parameter in express nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is how my get method looks like in my route file :

```
router.route('/:url')
  .get(myController.handle);
```

When I am testing my application I could run my code perfectly when I use this url : **localhost:3000/handle/www.something.com.** But when I change my url to a https it does not work, for example when I change it to : **http://localhost:3000/handle/https://verisign.com/** and return not found (404) error

Comment: Hi, This previous question might have the answer Enabling HTTPS on express.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

I replaced the / characters in the url with the ascii code(%2) and now it works.