# Deploying to AppEngine with HTTPS: JS file not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a simple project React + NodeJS project to app Engine. Both the frontend and backend are deployed within the same instance.

It currently works with HTTP (I have to manually change the URL to http when accessing it), however whenever I try changing the URL to HTTPS in my code, I get error

`GET https://sunlit-form-338718.nn.r.appspot.com/static/js/main.c2ecd1cd.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404.`

Why is it that I get this error only when I change my code to https? I run npm run build in client directory after every change.

in server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "../client/public/"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://sunlit-form-338718.nn.r.appspot.com");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

In App.js

```
    function hey(){
     axios.get(
         "https://sunlit-form-338718.nn.r.appspot.com/users", {withCredentials:true}).then(res =>{console.log(res)})

    }
```

In app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14

env: standard

env_variables:
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: sunlit-form-338718:northamerica-northeast1:sql-scratch-pw-root
# [END gae_mysql_env]

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

Project structure

```
Projet
 |
 +-- app.yaml
 |    
 +-- .gcloudignore
 |    
 +-- package.json
 |    
 +-- package-lock.json
 |    
 +-- client
 |  |  
 |  +-- build ...
 |  |  
 |  +-- node_modules ... 
 |  |  
 |  +-- public ...  
 |  |  
 |  +-- node_modules ... 
 |  +-- package.json
 |  |  
 |  +-- package.lock-json
 |    
 +-- server
 |  |  
 |  +-- server.js
 |  +-- node_modules
 |    
 +-- node_modules
 |  |  
 +  |-- dir 4.1
```

EDIT: More code

Package.json in client

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Package.json in root folder

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "server/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

index.html in build directory

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.836a6a76.js"></script>
    <link href="./static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

asset-manifest.json in build directory

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.css": "./static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css",
    "main.js": "./static/js/main.836a6a76.js",
    "static/js/787.db9b214f.chunk.js": "./static/js/787.db9b214f.chunk.js",
    "index.html": "./index.html",
    "main.e6c13ad2.css.map": "./static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css.map",
    "main.836a6a76.js.map": "./static/js/main.836a6a76.js.map",
    "787.db9b214f.chunk.js.map": "./static/js/787.db9b214f.chunk.js.map"
  },
  "entrypoints": [
    "static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css",
    "static/js/main.836a6a76.js"
  ]
}
```

full server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('../server/database')
const mysql = require("mysql2");


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "../client/public/"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://sunlit-form-338718.nn.r.appspot.com");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});




app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"users":["userOne", "userTwo", "userThree"]})

})

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {


        console.log("hi");
    
})
app.get('/*', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
```

Comment: Can you provide more code ( nodeJS ) ? contain package.

Comment: @JayLu sure! I just added the two package.json, index.html and asset-manifest.json

Comment: In the app.yaml, can you add the field `secure: always` in the handlers right after the url?

Comment: Actually, I mean I want to see more code of the server !
But, I suspect you might need this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js

Comment: oh sorry i just added the full server.js now. I tried adding secure: always but no good.

I actually don't have an ssl certificate, so I expected that the server calls wouldn't work, however I imagined the frontend should still be able to render.

It's very weird because the app is able to get the css files ./static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css but only the js causes problems