# How to disable http access in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, http, ssl, https

I have read that:

> Disable HTTP access to the domain, don’t even redirect or link it to SSL.This is the best practice against MITM and phising attacks.

so how can I access only `https` request not redirect `http` to `https`

disable http access

Comment: Weird advice, an http to https redirect is perfectly fine as long as it's a true redirect. That said: you can always use the native `https` module's `createServer` function with your `app` instead of using express' own `app.listen`.  See posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js for more information.

Comment: I'd suggest you not listen to this advice. Its the equivalent of "The safest way to drive is to: not drive." Set up https redirects, if you dont want the burden of doing that yourself cloudflare offers free http rewrites along with a multitude of other ssl/tls options.