# HTTPS redirection for all routes node.js/express - Security concerns

Tags: node.js, https, express

I recently took a stab at setting up HTTPS on a node/express server. I have successfully managed to redirect all the routes to use https using the code below:

```
// force https redirect
var https_redirect = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.secure) {
    if(env === 'development') {
      return res.redirect('https://localhost:3000' + req.url);
    } else {
      return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
  } else {
    return next();
  }
};

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  https_redirect(req, res, next);
});
```

This seems to be working fine. However, since I havent' dabbled into this before I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this the ideal way to redirect from http to https?
2. If a user uses the http route, prior to the redirect is it possible for anyone to use something like sslstrip to sniff out session info.

node: v0.8.2 ; express: v3.05

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure) {
        //FYI this should work for local development as well
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
    }
    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
app.get('/', routeHandlerHome);
```

The middleware approach will work because express will run the middleware in the order added, before it runs the router, and in general this kind of site-wide policy is cleaner as middleware vs. a wildcard route.

Regarding question 2 about sniffing session cookies, that must be addressed by marking the cookies as `secure` when you set them. If they haven't been marked secure, the browser will transmit them with HTTP requests as well, thus exposing them to sniffing.

Comment: This is great, but it's slightly problematic for development if you're using non-standard (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS), because it tries to redirect to `https://localhost:[PORT]`. A workaround is to set an `SSL_PORT` environment variable in the `development` environment, and, if it's defined, replace the port. See [here](https://gist.github.com/gingi/47df42a45bb1653002ee#file-gistfile1-js-L5-L8) for the modified snippet.

Comment: hei, how can I connect with a front-end client after doing this ? Thanks !

Comment: As a note, on heroku you have to use `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https'` or else this will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use your https_redirect function (though a bit modified) as a to automatically redirect all of your secure requests:

```
// force https redirect
var https_redirect = function () {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
      if(env === 'development') {
        return res.redirect('https://localhost:3000' + req.url);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
      }
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  };
};
app.use(https_redirect());

app.get('/', routeHandlerHome);
```

Comment: Hey Josh. Thanks for the reply. Can you highlight how your approach specifically with app . use would work as compared to my implementation.

Comment: @los7world: With app.use(), you're specifically setting up a middleware with no route matching, thus all your routes will pass through it.

Comment: Shouldn't this first condition be `!req.secure`

Answer (score 0):

I use this  simple code to redirect requests depending on whether the application is in development or production.

```
// force https redirect
var forceHTTPS = function () {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure) {
      if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
         return res.redirect('https://localhost:3001' + req.url);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
      }
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  };
};
```