# Nodejs Link Shortener - Using an API

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working on a new app that includes a link redirect facility based on a shortlink. There are three parts to the application:

1. Back-office for clients to login and add new shortened links (uses the API)
2. Nodejs application that receives the request (when a someone clicks on a shortened link) and redirects accordingly (uses the API)
3. The API itself

I am intending to use Basic Auth to secure the API (which requires an SSL connection to maintain security) but I would like the short urls to be a non-secure web address (http) if the client wants them to be.

**Question**
How can I keep the http for the short links but still make a secure connection to the API to see where the shortlink should re-redirect to?

Could I somehow turn the http into https in the node application before processing?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Note:** I'm hosting my application(s) on Heroku.

Comment: Run Node behind nginx. Create sites that serve on both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I don't get it. API stores whatever URL you throw at it and does a redirect to that exact URL later on? How are these two parts related?

Comment: The node app will talk to the API to establish the actual URL. Once Node app receives the response (the real URL) then it will redirect. Have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1):

When using [https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html), if the client connects with http he will use http. If you want to turn it automatically to https use that :

```
app.get('/api/*',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']!='https')
    res.redirect('https://mypreferreddomain.com'+req.url)
  else
    next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
})
```

at the top of your routes. [Heroku NodeJS http to https ssl forced redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect)

Comment: This looks very useful - will have a play around with it now