# Non-secure website error using Stripe API

Tags: node.js, security, heroku, stripe-payments

I created a shopping cart webpage in Node.js using the Stripe API and when I deployed it to Heroku I was getting a not secure webpage error my error is:

> Your connection to this site is not secure
>   You should not enter any sensitive information on this site (for example, passwords or credit cards), because it could be stole by attackers

Is there something that I can do to stop this because no images are loaded I only get this error in google Chrome. In Safari and Firefox I don't even get an error, but the images wont load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force your Heroku app to listen only on https. If you are using Express, this can be done using the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your site (or at least, the page with the payment form) is served over HTTPS.

Cf. Stripe's documentation for more information: https://stripe.com/docs/security#tls.