# Where to handle the redirection from HTTP to HTTPs?

Tags: express, http, heroku, https

I have a heroku application with a domain from godaddy.

My site is built with node and express.

My website is www.juanitacalendar.de and I want it to always redirect to HTTPS (no matter if the users types the www or not).

Should I handle this within Heroku? Within node/express? In my index.html?

I've read in another answer that I'm suppose to use this code that has to do with apache. I am clueless on where to put this piece of code though.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you *could* achieve this.

In your situation, it looks like you can get Node/Express.js to redirect for you. See this answer for more information: [Heroku NodeJS http to https ssl forced redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect/23894573#23894573).